# Android canvas - gap in corner where path closes

Tags: android, canvas, path

I have a pretty simple path.

It draws a few lines, and then for the last line, that is supposed to join back to the starting point of the path, leaves a small notch in the corner where it is supposed to join.

[image]

I would like this corner to be joined like the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by setting a variable on my paint object:

```
myPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.SQUARE)
```